# how to retrieve a content of a table in database(with html tags)

Tags: php

i have made some inputs in my database table and it is saved together with its html tags.
now, i want it to be downloaded by a user.
i want to remove the html tags.
Since the file input at my database table has no format, i want the download file to be downloaded as a document file and must be compatible in MS word.

so far i have this for the download page

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
include 'connect.php';


$id    = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, content, format FROM activity WHERE id = '$id'");

list($title, $content, $format) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
strip_tags($content);
header("Content-type: $format");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$title");
echo $content;

mysql_close;
exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: And what happens when you run that?

Comment: `echo $content;` what it gives you ?

Comment: the download prompt will appear. and the i download the file. and i open it in MS WOrd, it shows the content i saved with the html tags.

Comment: PHP's `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  The [suggested alternatives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) also happen to be [easy to use safely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/132382).

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one only problem on your script:

First of all, if you're sure there's only 1 value return by your query, add LIMIT 1.
Then, to return your value, use 
    $contents = $result[0]['content'];

Moreover, filename is the filename, not the content.
Finally, read some docs about HTTP headers: Content-Disposition is not sufficient to send your file, even you're wanted to be compatible with MSword...

"the download prompt will appear. and the i download the file. and i open it in MS WOrd, it shows the content i saved with the html tags"
=> maybe you just htmlentities your tag in the database.
Try this:

```
<?php
strip_tags(html_entity_decode($contents));
?>
```

Comment: About LIMIT 1 - 

I think id is primary key :)

Comment: it still has the tags. im using firefox, and at the prompt it says that my file is a PHP script.